# Sum value in google sheet with countif or any function

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Sorry for my bad english. I am trying to sum value from selected column using countif. this is [my sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7wetm.png). and how can I get total quantity of milk chocolate. The result must be **310** (125 + 145 + 40). Please help me out

Comment: What have you tried or researched so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [**SUMIF**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093583) which returns a conditional sum across a range.

**Syntax:**

```
SUMIF(range, criterion, [sum_range])
```

**Sample:**

```
=SUMIF(A1:A6,"Milk Chocolate",B1:B6)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
=SUM(FILTER(E6:E; D6:D="Milk Chocolate"))
```